# HTML5 input type=number and the placeholder attribute

Tags: html, input, numbers, placeholder

Is there any way to use placeholder on `<input type=number>`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've just checked against the HTML5 spec for input where a type is number and it explicitly says that the placeholder [attribute may not be used](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/number-state.html#number-state). I also had errors with http://validator.w3.org when I tried to validate html with an input type of number with a placeholder attribute. Looks like browsers may support this but it's not valid in the HTML5 spec.

Comment: Don't think this statement is valid anymore, the newest draft has added it. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-input-placeholder (scroll up a bit for the yellow spotted table)

Answer (score 1):

@zachleat is correct, the `placeholder` attribute is allowed in the latest HTML5 spec:

[HTML 5.1 2nd Edition: forms, number-state-typenumber](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/PR-html51-20170803/sec-forms.html#number-state-typenumber) (see the bookkeeping section)

> The following common input element content attributes apply to the element: autocomplete, list, max, min, **placeholder**, readonly, required, and step content attributes;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Placeholders section in the MDN Web Docs about `<input type="number">`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Placeholders

> Sometimes it's helpful to offer an in-context hint as to what form the input data should take. This can be especially important if the page design doesn't offer descriptive labels for each `<input>`. This is where **placeholders** come in. A placeholder is a value that demonstrates the for the `value` should take by presenting an example of a valid value, which is displayed inside the edit box when the element's `value` is `""`. Once data is entered into the box, the placeholder disappears; if the box is emptied, the placeholder reappears.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Placeholder:** `<input type="number" placeholder="10">`

**Using Min and Max Values:** `<input type="number" placeholder="10">`

**Using Value:** `<input type="number" value="10">`